# Calculate $a+2b^2+3c^3+4d^4$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Hello I wanted to get some help in how to follow.

I have an excercise that it's like this:

**It is known that**

$$\int_{2}^{3} \frac{x^2-3x+2}{x^2-x+1} \,\mathrm dx = a\ln(7)+b\ln(3)+c\ln(2)+d$$
**where a,b,c,d are integers.**

Calculate : $$a+2b^2+3c^3+4d^4$$
And I know the answer is $5$, however I don't know how to arrive to it.
what I did was calculate this integral and it gave me $1+\ln 12-\ln 28$ so I know that $d=1$
however I am lost on how to follow.
I tried comparing it like this:
$$\ln(7^a.3^b.2^c) +1 =1+\ln\left(\frac{12}{28}\right) $$
But this is as far as I got, I imagine there must be something I am missing here so I would appreciate if you could give me a small tip so I can arrive at the solution

Comment: Hint: $\ln(12) = \ln(2^2 \cdot 3)$ and $\ln(28) = \ln(2^2 \cdot 7)$. Try expanding these logarithms out.

Comment: Hint: $ln(ab) = ln(a) + ln(b)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral results to me

$$1+\log 3-\log 7$$

thus

$$\begin{cases}
a=-1 \\
b=1 \\
c=0 \\
d=1
\end{cases}$$

that is

$$-1+2+0+4=5$$